# Transparent Cutout Shader with _Color property in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, transparent

I'm using this shader [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/273680/transparent-cutout-shader.html) in the answers. My goal is mostly to fade in and out objects which works fine in most cases. Only [this colored bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDj2K.png) is not completely shown.

There is another object behind it, but in the beginning it's invisible.

Now my problem is: Why is the colored bar not completely shown? (it is in front of the invisible other object)

I'm new to unity shader programming, so I'm really lost about the code >.< 
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem please? It seems that the shader you got works in most context so can you describe precisely when it does not?

Comment: At first I'm sorry I got the wrong Link >.< right now I got the shader from here, maybe the question here is even more precise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677847/unity-gameobjects-invisible thanks for your fast reply :)