# unity: gameobjects invisible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, transparent

I combined two shaders which can show transparency and cutoff Alpha. It works pretty fine, just two small problems stay. 
(1) in some specific camera angles the cutoff regions of an object are visible (only if a another object with the same shader is located behind that one) 
(2) if I fade out an object it's getting black not transparent

I'm new to shader-coding, thanks a lot for your help!!

Here's the shader:

```
Shader "Unlit/MyTransparent"
{
Properties{
    _Color("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,0.5)
    _MainTex("Base (RGB) Alpha (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Cutoff("Base Alpha cutoff", Range(0,0.9)) = 0.5

}
    Category{
    //Tags{ "QUEUE" = "AlphaTested" "IGNOREPROJECTOR" = "true" "RenderType" = "Transparent" } // Transparent beides
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

    SubShader{ 

        Material{
        Diffuse[_Color]
        Ambient[_Color]
    }

        Pass{
            AlphaTest Greater[_Cutoff]
            SetTexture[_MainTex]{
            combine texture * primary, texture
        }
        } 

        Pass{
        GLSLPROGRAM
            varying mediump vec2 uv;

            uniform mediump vec4 _MainTex_ST;
            void main() {
                gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
                uv = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy * _MainTex_ST.xy + _MainTex_ST.zw;
            }

            uniform lowp sampler2D _MainTex;
            uniform lowp vec4 _Color;
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(_MainTex, uv) * _Color;
                float ca = tex2D(_CutTex, IN.uv_MainTex).a;
            }

        ENDGLSL
} 

        Pass{
        ZWrite Off 
        SetTexture[_MainTex]{
            //combine texture * primary, texture
            Combine texture * constant ConstantColor[_Color] 
        }
}
}

    SubShader{ Pass{
    SetTexture[_MainTex]{ Combine texture * constant ConstantColor[_Color]}
} }
}
```

}

Comment: Is the line where it sets float ca supposed to be there? _CutTex isn't declared and tex2D is a Cg function not a GLSL one.

Comment: I don't know to be honest... I now combined two shaders line by line seeing what happens. It's working pretty fine now! My next two problems are:  (1) objects which are faded out are not transparent but black (2) you can see in some specific camera angles the cutoff-parts of the objects (of course before fading...) (I'm updating my question :) I would be really happy if you could have another look at my code!!! thank you so much)

Comment: Some concepts: Unity shaders are written in ShaderLab. ShaderLab can in turn contain shader programs in 3 languages: Cg - denoted by CGPROGRAM tags, GLSL - denoted by GLSLPROGRAM, and fixed function which isn't really a language and isn't widely used any more (No tags, but they'll contain the word Combine). You can't mix the languages. There's no real reason to pick Cg or GLSL other than familiarity, they work pretty much the same.

Comment: The Unity docs on ShaderLab are good for ShaderLab itself, but they don't teach the shader programming languages.
Cg docs: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/index.html
GLSL docs: https://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/

Comment: Sometimes you'll run into a shader written in HLSL. Cg and HLSL are so similar you can pretty much treat it as Cg.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! I'll try to get through all the shader stuff... do you have a tip for my problem here?